# I want to share my Flask app to another person who doesnt have the dependencies installed

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, cx-freeze

I have created a flask app and wanted to share it to my friend who doesn't have any dependencies installed . I tried the method of using CX_Freeze but the build option leads to a link opening which i get an error saying  .
my setup.py looks like this
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

Include the name of all folder or files in your project folder that is necessary for the project excluding your main flask file.

If there are multiple files, you can add them into a folder and then specify the folder name.

In place of main.py file add your main flask file name

```
includefiles = [ 'hello', 'go.py']

includes = [ 'jinja2' , 'jinja2.ext']

excludes = ['Tkinter']

setup(

name='Ubicare',

version = '0.1',

description = 'Sample Flask App',

options = {'build_exe': {'excludes':excludes,'include_files':includefiles, 'includes':includes}},

executables = [Executable('go.py')]

)
```

This error is what i get :

[image]

Please Help !

Comment: How to fix it ??

Comment: Please: edit your question in a more readable way (and add more data on what you did)  If you have an error, copy it: please no screen shots! Why cannot your friend install dependencies?